# Show that if $Y=\begin{bmatrix}I&Z\\ 0&I\end{bmatrix}$ then $\kappa_F(Y)=\|Y\|_F\cdot\|Y^{-1}\|_F=2n+\|Z\|_F^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Show that if $Y=\begin{bmatrix}I_n&Z\\ 0&I_n\end{bmatrix}$, where $I_n$ is identity matrix, then $\kappa_F(Y)=\|Y\|_F\cdot\|Y^{-1}\|_F=2n+\|Z\|_F^2$

My book doesn't elaborate too much on the Frobenius norm, but here's what I gathered. Let me know if the definition is wrong.

By definition, $\kappa_F(Y) = \Vert Y\Vert_F \Vert Y^{-1} \Vert_F = \sqrt{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sigma_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}\right)}$

So I'm assuming after this is carried out on the matrix that the $2n$ expression comes from the Identity submatrices, the rest is left to Z, but how should I formulate that?

Comment: I added a subscript to $I$ as it was hard to figure out dimensions.  Why don't you start by writing out $Y^{-1}$?

Comment: The Frobenius norm of a matrix $A = (a_{i,j})_{i,j}$ is the squareroot of the sum of the squares of all entries $\sqrt{\sum_{i,j} |a_{i,j}|^2}$. Because of the shape of $Y$ it is easy to calculate its inverse. The exercise is then a straightforward calculation (and yes, the $2n$ comes from the identity matrices). Notice the Frobeinius norm for $Z$ is the Frobenius norm for $n\times n$ matrices while the Frobenius norm for $Y$ is the Frobenius norm for $2n \times 2n$ matrices.

Comment: I got $Y^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}I_n&-Z\\ 0&I_n\end{bmatrix}$. Lot simpler than I thought it was going to be

Comment: So did I get the definition of the condition number wrong? I'll just compute with the standard def.

Comment: Also, how do I write the componentwise summation indices for the Frobenius norm of the Z matrix values? I stated that $\sum_{i=j}^{2n} 1^2$ for the Identity matrices

Comment: Nevermind, got it